# Word VBA: Will unnecessary property flags slow down a macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro with hundreds of find and replace operations formatted as, for example:

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "can't"
    .Font.Italic = False
    .Replacement.Text = "cannot"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

I'm aware that all the `.MatchCase = False` etcs are unnecessary after the first time they're set to False, as Match Case will stay False until it's turned to True. My question is whether in a large macro like mine with hundreds of Replace operations and thousands of lines, will those unnecessary lines slow it down?

I just want to know if it'll make a difference before I spend ages going through and removing redundant lines.

(please don't shout at me for bad practice, the macro came together quite organically and became an official project when it was already really big)

Cheers!

Comment: It will probably slow down, but the amount of extra time is so low that you will never be able to measure it. The real work is the replace itself, and this takes magnitudes more time than to execute some (precompiled) statements that only set the search properties

Comment: The biggest performance drags will be your use of Selection and allowing the screen to update with each F/R operation...

Answer (score 3):

The redundant lines won’t slow your operations down more than your use of `Selection` is already doing.

Replacing your hundreds of find and replace operations with code like this will speed things up a lot.

```
Sub CallingRoutine()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   FindAndReplace "can't", "cannot"
   FindAndReplace "don't", "do not"
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
    
Sub FindAndReplace(findText As String, replaceText As String)
   With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .Text = findText
      .Font.Italic = False
      .Replacement.Text = replaceText
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is essentially will setting a flag to its default value would significantly hinder runtime performance. In short, the answer is no.

I went ahead and performed a test for you and setting a value to a property 1 million times, and here was the result:

[image]

Setting the `MatchCase` property **1 million times** was so insignificant that it was quicker than 1 thousandths of a second.

So don't be worried about setting values to properties, even if the value is equal to the property's default.

With all that being said, performance varies greatly depending on your hardware. My testing hardware is probably not what would be used in most scenarios, but it doesn't really change the fact that you shouldn't have concern on setting these values.

For reference, I am running:

- CPU: i9-10900KF
- Memory: 32GB ADATA Running XMP @ 3200 MHz
- MB: Asus TUF Z490 Plus

---

I even ran another test, setting the value to True/False a million times, and obtained the same results:

[image]

And for those who want precise numbers:

[image]

Comment: On my system, repeating *all* the F/R settings (except for the actual F/R expressions and the .Execute line) 100,000 times takes 11 seconds.

Comment: Right, which is expected. But those are also necessary settings to change. OP wanted to know if setting values to _”unnecessary”_ (which I would assume default properties already set from what it sounded like) would make a significant difference or not.

Comment: Mostly, those settings would not be necessary to change on each F/R operation. I have coded many F/R sequences over the years and have rarely found a need to change attributes mid-stream. And, where changes are needed, the solution has been to structure the code so that as few changes as possible need to be made, without unnecessarily resetting parameters that don't need changing.

Comment: I never said they were necessary. I simply replied to OP’s question as it was asked. He stated he has been given a huge wall of code and instead of removing all the redundant lines wanted to know if he should just keep as-is. I never advocated that he should include these settings.

Comment: Sure there is certainly some optimization that could be done. If he’s seeking that kind of assistance it would probably be better off in [codereview.se] though.